# USING limit/offset in a JOIN query

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have 4 tables

1. A user account

   ```
   user_id | username | password                           
   ---------+----------+----------
   ```
2. A projects table

   ```
    project_id |         project_name         | category_id 
    ------------+------------------------------+-------------
   ```
3. A user_projects table (many to many relationship)

   ```
   accounts_projects_id | account_id | project_id 
   ----------------------+------------+------------
   ```
4. A project_messages table (a project will have many messages)

   ```
   message_id | project_id |message| username 
   ------------+------------+--------+---------
   ```

At login, I'm running a query where I fetch the number of projects a user belongs to and the messages for each project using the below query

```
SELECT account.user_id,account.username,
       array_agg(json_build_object('message',project_messages.message,'username',project_messages.username)) AS messages,
project.project_name 
FROM account 
  JOIN accounts_projects ON account.user_id  = accounts_projects.account_id
  JOIN project_messages ON accounts_projects.project_id = project_messages.project_id
  JOIN project ON project.project_id = accounts_projects.project_id
WHERE account.username=$1 
GROUP BY project.project_name,account.user_id
```

this gives me the below output

```
userid,username, messages (json array object),project_name`
87;"kannaj";"{"{\"message\" : \"saklep\", \"username\" : \"kannaj\"}"}";"Football with Javascript"
87;"kannaj";"{"{\"message\" : \"work\", \"username\" : \"kannaj\"}","{\"message\" : \"you've been down to long in the midnight sea\", \"username\" : \"kannaj\"}","{\"message\" : \"Yeaaaa\", \"username\" : \"house\"}"}";"Machine Learning with Python"
87;"kannaj";"{"{\"message\" : \"holyy DIVVEERRR\", \"username\" : \"kannaj\"}"}";"Beethoven with react"
```

Is there a way I can use the LIMIT/OFFSET function when retrieving the messages from the project_messages table?

Comment: Use subquery or use subarray like `(array_agg(...))[3:5]`

Comment: the subarray throws a syntax error :( .. where should i place the subquery?

Comment: @Elad It limits whole table, not each group.

Comment: @Elad - this creates a limit on the number of rows on the overall output and not on the column

Comment: is there a better way i can run the query? am i going wrong somewhere else?

Comment: its like a basic chat room really ... a project could have 100 messages .. i only want to fetch the latest 10 messages from the project_messages table

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To make our examples simpler lets say we have two linked tables:

```
t1(id);
t2(id, t1_id);
```

And query is

```
select t1.id, array_agg(t2.id)
from t1 join t2 on (t1.id = t2.t1_id)
group by t1.id;
```

It is very simplified variant of the your large query as you can see.

1) Arrays

```
select t1.id, (array_agg(t2.id order by t2.id desc))[3:5]
from t1 join t2 on (t1.id = t2.t1_id)
group by t1.id;
```

This query works just as original, but returns only from 3,4 and 5 elements of the array which is equal to `offset 2 limit 3`.

2) Subquery and `lateral`

```
select
  t1.id,
  array_agg(t.x)
from
  t1 join lateral 
    (select t2.id as x from t2 where t1.id = t2.t1_id order by t2.id desc offset 2 limit 3) t on (true)
group by t1.id;
```

Here `lateral` keyword allows to use fields from other tables mentioned in the main `from` clause in our subquery (`t1.id`).

Comment: I'm getting a syntax error when using the slice operator .. ```ERROR:  syntax error at or near "["``` :( ... i cant seem to use the lateral keywords when there are other joins .. is there something i'm missing?

Comment: @Kunkka 1) Enclose whole `array_agg` function into the brackets: `(array_agg(...))[n:m]` 2) Check my editing, it is more easy to understand.

Comment: it works now :) .. i have another question now though .. is there someway to also include an ORDER BY clause?

Comment: thank you  .. i actually read up a bit on lateral .. i think your second example is a bit more flexible .. woudnt you say?

Comment: @Kunkka Flexibility is almost same. Second example probably is more efficient at the performance point. It is up to you which one to use for your task.